# Delphi XE2: Sharing a variable between two different processes?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, ipc

I need to share the value of a Boolean variable between 2 running programs (e.g. MyProgramA.exe and MyProgramB.exe); these are different programs, not instances of the same program. I would prefer a global variable in memory over IPC with Windows messages because I think setting a global variable in memory which can be accessed by different programs is faster (i.e. instantaneous), more secure and more reliable than IPC with Windows messages.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? There's tons of different ways to do this and tons of resources to show you how. The thing is, this is considered a "shopping list" question which will likely be closed because there are too many different possible answers.

Comment: I am not aware of any way to share a global variable between different processes. I did a Google search which did not give me a proper answer to this question.
So if there are tons of different ways to do this, please name just a few of the best ones, so I can continue my research.

Comment: In a Google search, this was my first result right here on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646202/sharing-data-array-between-two-applications-in-delphi

Comment: And another: http://delphi.cjcsoft.net/viewthread.php?tid=49425 (Well that's file based but the point is I have a lot of Google results searching for "delphi share variable between processes")

Comment: All of the standard IPC methods can do this, but none of them are real "shared variables" or "instantaneous". Since you're familiar with the phrase IPC, do some research on the various methods of doing so, narrow down the options you're considering to a couple of them, and then ask a *specific* question related to those selected options. (I question your "more secure and more reliable" conclusion, too. If two different processes can access it, something else can as well via various mechanisms.) IMO, this question is very broad in scope and pretty vague in its current form.

Comment: Thanks for the links. With "instantaneous" I mean that there should be no need to send a message from one program to the other program. It should work like a global interface variable between modules in the same program.

Comment: As I said before, there are no true "global shared variables" between processes, and nothing between processes is as "instantaneous" as a true variable in a process. IPC involves crossing process boundaries, and there is some overhead involved in doing that regardless of the mechanism you choose. Safely sharing a variable between threads in the *same* process has some overhead; doing so between *different* processes has more.

Comment: What about synchronization?

Answer (score 5):

You can allocate a block of shared memory using the Win32 API `CreateFileMapping()` function, and then use the `MapViewOfFile()` function to access that memory.  Both processes need to call `CreateFileMapping()` with the same name in order to share the same mapping, but they will each receive their own local view of the mapping.

For example:

```
uses
  ..., Windows;

var
  Mapping: THandle = 0;
  MyBoolean: PBoolean = nil;

...

Mapping := CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, nil, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, SizeOf(Boolean), 'MyMappedBoolean');
if Mapping <> 0 then
  MyBoolean := PBoolean(MapViewOfFile(Mapping, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, SizeOf(Boolean));

...

if MyBoolean <> nil then
  MyBoolean^ := ...;

...

if MyBoolean <> nil then
begin
  if MyBoolean^ then
    ...
  else
    ...
end;

...

if MyBoolean <> nil then
  UnmapViewOfFile(MyBoolean);
if Mapping <> 0 then
  CloseHandle(Mapping);
```

Comment: Can I call `CreateFileMapping` in FormCreate and then keep the shared memory block during the whole run time of the program? Do I need to free the shared memory when the program closes?

Comment: Yes, you can use it for the lifetime of the process. No, you do not need to free it, as the OS automatically closes open handles when a process terminates, and a file mapping is auto-freed when all of its handles are closed. However, out of good programming practice, you should free anything you allocate, so you should explicitly unmap and close the mapping when you are done using it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! how would you unmap and close the mapping?

Comment: `UnmapViewOfFile()` and `CloseHandle()`, respectively.