# What function has replaced GlobalAlloc in Win32?

Tags: windows, winapi, ipc

Since `GlobalAlloc` has become local in the 32 bit model, it can't be used so that allocated memory to be shared between Win32 applications. What function is replacing `GlobalAlloc` and uses the same simplicity? (Like retrieving a handler to the memory block, which is converted to pointer later by the application that uses it.)

Answer (score 6):

The way you share memory between processes in Win32 is with memory mapped files. Start with `CreateFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile`.

Comment: See this question for some examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646202/sharing-data-array-between-two-applications-in-delphi/5647187#5647187

Answer (score 0):

If you are after general IPC rather than just shared memory, I would suggest reading the ["Interprocess Communications"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#base.using_a_file_mapping_for_ipc) chapter. It seems you could use named memory mappings as the closest equivalent of `GlobalAlloc()`.