# Is there a way to notify another application about changes to shared memory?

Tags: windows, delphi, push-notification, thread-safety, shared-memory

In reference to the question [Sharing data array between two applications in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646202/sharing-data-array-between-two-applications-in-delphi/5646603#5646603) I would like to know whether it is possible to send an event to another application sharing the memory?

If a process has data to consume it needs to know it's there.

And one more question, is this method of sharing "thread safe"?

Comment: You can e.g. wait for some system object (like mutex, or named event). Or post a registered Windows message. But to be more specific we need to know what processes do you have, e.g. if it's a desktop and service app. combination (if they reside in the same session).

Comment: If you are going to need to notify the other app, then why are you using shared memory. Shared memory is not your ideal IPC option here. You want a message passing approach.

Comment: @TLama :we are talking about two windows application that have the uid to access the memory as the example show. the code could not be uniform(not same code on all running applications).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the reason im going for shared memory, is to know if the other application is open, and what does it hold. i need two way comunication. one diraction is info on app state and the other direction, pass event. how can i pass messages between apps , and what data do i need to pass that message?

Comment: That's a much broader question. Shared memory is almost certainly a very bad idea here. An exceptionally bad idea most likely. Unfortunately you've asked a question having already chosen the wrong solution.

Comment: @David, [`are you sure`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14740/Fast-IPC-Communication-Using-Shared-Memory-and-Int) ?

Comment: @TLama How can you tell that ultimate performance is the key driver here?

Comment: @David, well, at least I wouldn't say it's an exceptionally bad idea.

Comment: @TLama Wait until you try to maintain code written this way. Then you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Why not use named pipes? They're *designed* for two-way communication.

Comment: the 'push notifocations' tag is specific for mobile apps